# How to scale an image to fit a screen

Tags: html, css

I have a page that I am making and I have made the footer an image... My problem is that the image is 1920x122 and it doe this when I add it to a webpage:
[image]
How do I scale the image to fit the screen (I want this to work for all screens)?
Preferably CSS and HTML only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following property to the CSS styling for your footer:

```css
  width: 100vw;
```

This sets the width of the image to 100% of the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

Try these in your CSS if you want it to cover the entire screen:

```
  background-image: *insert url*
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
```

Or adjust the height if you only want partial etc...

Comment: I don't want this to be a background image. or cover the whole screen